# ajax for loop get first element src

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
  for (var obj in d){
    if (d.hasOwnProperty(obj) && d[obj].hasOwnProperty('src') && d   
    [obj].src !== '')
        {
            var type1 = d[obj].src;
            alert(type1)[0]; // which is the first element src
            var mainsrc = type1[0] // return "i" letter 4 times.
        }
    }
```

**conlog d[obj].src**

```
Img/House/type1/Image1.png // i only need this one.
Img/House/type1/Image2.png
Img/House/type1/Image3.png
Img/House/type1/Image4.png
```

i am using for loop in ajax , and i got the data return but i only need the first element src , but i had no idea how to get it , i don't wanted to use loop again inside a loop , but is it no other possible way?

Comment: can you elaborate your question add some more code

Comment: Do not iterate the loop then.

Comment: `d[obj].src` - what is it? array/object/string?

Comment: If it's an object, there is no *"first"* element, but who knows what you've got ?

Comment: your alert is incorrect: alert(type1[0]) work.

Comment: type1[0] get me letter "I" 4 times

Comment: is a object in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `break` keyword in after the first loop as such:

```
 for (var obj in d){
    if (d.hasOwnProperty(obj) && d[obj].hasOwnProperty('src') && d   
    [obj].src !== '')
        {
            var type1 = d[obj].src;
            alert(type1)[0]; // which is the first element src
            var mainsrc = type1[0] // return "i" letter 4 times.
            break; // Break the loop. Continue with code below
        }
 }
 console.log('Other code that will be run after the break;');
```

Answer (score -1):

When you're in a for loop, you can terminate it with the `break` keyword. So after you've gotten the first item you're looking for, you can break out.

Comment: `continue` or `break`